# Using PHP Namespace in hierarchy directory structure Error

Tags: php, namespaces

I am working with a folder structure as follows:

```
classes
    -common.php
    -core.php
modules
    -index/index.php
```

I am trying to use the common.php in my index.php file and I am facing error:

> Fatal error: Class 'classes\Common' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\devmyproject\modules\index\index.php on line 7

My Code:

**commom.php class:**

```
**Directory:/root/classes/common.php**
<?php
namespace classes;

class Common
{

    function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

My **index.php** file which try to use the classes/commom.php

```
**Directory:/root/modules/index/index.php**
<?php
namespace modules\beneficiary;
use \classes as hp; 
include_once 'config.php';
$common = new \classes\Common();
//To Get Page Labels
$labels = $common->getPageLabels('1');
```

I am includeing common.php in config.php

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($classes);
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile())
        include_once 'classes/' . $file;
}
```

My Try:

It works fine when I use the folder structure as follows:

```
classes
    -common.php
    -core.php
modules
    -index.php
```

If I use another folder inside modules it get error? I am not sure about he hierarchy of folders when using namespace can some one help me?

Comment: Namespaces and folder hierarchies are two entirely unrelated things. How are you *including the files* the classes are in?

Comment: I have shown it in my question.

Comment: I don't see where you `include 'common.php'`.

Comment: It is included in include_once 'config.php';

Comment: And config.php includes common.php...?!

Comment: check my edit in question.

Comment: Then please say so!?!? We can't guess that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) *common.php* in *index.php* (better: use one of its relatives `include_once` or `require_once`) or set up an autoloader using [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (or, not recommended, writing an [`__autoload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function).

Comment: I have properly included also checked it using get_include_files().